# Json array don't print value in jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp

I'm making a dynamic search in jsp.
It begins with Filter.java mapped as filter.json . Using two different methods I correctly save on 2 ArrayList the result of the search on SQL.
This is Filter.java

```
class Filter() {
    ...
    ArrayList<News> newsListCat = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<News> newsListAut = new ArrayList<>();
    NewsFactory newsFactory = NewsFactory.getInstance();
    String str = request.getParameter("q");

    if (str.equals("search")) {

        String toSearch = request.getParameter("toSearch");

        if (toSearch == null) {
            newsListCat = newsFactory.getNews();
        } else {
            newsListCat = newsFactory.searchNewsbyCat(toSearch);
            newsListAut = newsFactory.searchNewsbyAut(toSearch);
            //System.out.println(newsListAut);

        }
    }

    request.setAttribute("newsListCat", newsListCat);
    request.setAttribute("newsListAut", newsListAut);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT");

    request.getRequestDispatcher("data.jsp").forward(request, response);
    ...
}
```

It send the request in data.jsp that manage json array

```
<json:array>
<c:forEach var="news" items="${newsListAut}">
    <json:object>
        <json:property name="type" value="author"/>
        <json:property name="newsID" value="${news.getID()}"/>
        <json:property name="authorID" value="${news.getAuthor().getID()}"/>
        <json:property name="name" value="${news.getAuthor().getName()}"/>
        <json:property name="surname" value="${news.getAuthor().getSurname()}"/>
    </json:object>
</c:forEach>
<c:forEach var="news" items="${newsListCat}">
    <json:object>
        <json:property name="type" value="category"/>
        <json:property name="authorID" value="${news.getAuthor().getID()}"/>
        <json:property name="name" value="${news.getAuthor().getName()}"/>
        <json:property name="surname" value="${news.getAuthor().getSurname()}"/>
    </json:object>
</c:forEach>
```

In the end search.js should run the request creating dynamically an unordered list with the result of the query.
The response of request is right, but the jsp page doesn't do anything.

search.js

```
    function stateSuccess(data) {

        var ResultCat = $("newsListCat");
        $(ResultCat).empty();

        var ResultAut = $("newsListAut");
        $(ResultAut).empty();

        for (var instance in data) {
            if (data[instance].type === "category") {
                $(ResultCat).append("<li><a href='notizie.html?cat=" + data[instance].category + "'>" + data[instance].category + "</a></li>");
            } else if (data[instance].type === "author")
                $(ResultAut).append("<a href='profilo.html?id=" + data[instance].authorID + "}'><li>" + data[instance].name + " " + data[instance].surname + "</li></a>");
        }
    }

    function stateFailure(data, state) {
        console.log(state);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search").keyup(function (event) {
            //$("input").css("background-color", "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)");
            $.ajax({
                url: "filter.json",
                data: {
                    q: "search",
                    toSearch: event.target.value
                },
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function (data, state) {
                    stateSuccess(data);
                },
                error: function (data, state) {
                    stateFailure(data, state);
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I think so but don't know what.
[This is how the search request result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTiDH.png)

Answer (score 0):

By the time you click "search" the jsp page is loaded and is empty.

When you click search, ajax call gets data for you, but the jsp page is not loaded and is still empty.

Use your stateSuccess function to put data in jsp page.